# Search Bar outside ActIonBar in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-search

I want to add a search bar in my application, similar to what Zomato does. I have searched a lot and I have learnt search interface is the way to go, but everywhere I have seen it has been added in the action bar whereas I want it in some fragment(fixed activity). Is there any other way search could be added(how zomato does it)?

Is it necessary to open another activity to do the search or I could open another fragment to do the same?

Comment: SearchView is a nornal View,  so you can add it everywhere

Answer (score 0):

Like @pskink said, you can add the SearchView anywhere in your layout, like this:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </SearchView>
    </LinearLayout>
```